# Xcode swift table view only showing one data value and not all

Tags: arrays, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app i am trying to have the users be able to see their posts. Right now the user can only see their most recent post and for some reason not all of the posts are going through and getting added to the "myPosts" array. When i print "postDict" which is a Dictionary  it gives me all the correct values of which posts that user has made, but for one reason the data is not going through and getting added to the array. Please help and refer to the comments in the code and my JSON Tree.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MockPostVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var mockPost: MockPost!

var myposts = [MockPost]()
var postKey: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    DataSevice.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.child("posts").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock:  { snapshot in

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshots{

                var y = "\(snap)"
                var x = y.componentsSeparatedByString("Snap (")
                var z = x[1].componentsSeparatedByString(") 1")

                DataSevice.ds.REF_POSTS.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                    self.myposts = []
                    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                        for snap in snapshots{

                            if "\(z[0])" != snap.key{
                            }
                            else{
                                if let postDict = snap.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?{

                                    self.postKey = snap.key
                                    let mockPost = MockPost(dictionary: postDict, postKey: snap.key)
                                    self.myposts.append(mockPost)
                                    //self.myposts.count returns as 1
                                    //for some reason only the first post is getting registered into the array
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    })
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myposts.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let mockPost = myposts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MockPostCell") as? MockPostCell {
        cell.request?.cancel()
        cell.configureCell(mockPost, postKey: postKey!)

        return cell
    } else {
        return MockPostCell()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to show all the posts of one specific user, you have to remove this line `self.myposts = []` in your post handler closure, have a try.